# Is there a special name for these big balloony toys in parks? (image included)

Tags: single-word-requests

Do these toys have a common widely-accepted name?

[image: Inflatable play structure]

Comment: *Brinca-Brinca* is the term we use in more hispanically oriented english speaking regions of the US.

Answer (score 45):

In the UK they are often called ['*Bouncy Castles*'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bouncy-castle?s=t), however when they don't bear any resemblance to a castle they are sometimes called, merely, [*'Inflatables'*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inflatable?s=t)

> Inflatable - **noun**
>
> 1 - any of various large air-filled objects made of strong plastic or rubber, used for children to play on at fairs, carnivals, etc.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Comment: A "bouncy castle" is a special type of inflatable that is enclosed and its only real purpose is to allow people (kids) to jump up and down. (And yes, they often look like small inflated multicolor castles). The pictured inflatable is sort of a bouncy obstacle course.

Comment: At least where I'm from (Southern US) I've heard people call all these things 'bouncy castles' even when they look like something else. But don't mind us: we also call all sodas 'Coke'.

Comment: Anything like this ('castle' or not) I know, and have often heard described, as 'bouncy castle'.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist the proper term is "pop" ;)

Comment: I (from the UK) would call the item in the picture a "bouncy castle", despite it not looking much like a castle.

Comment: I'd (UK) call it a "bouncy castle" too.  It's more "architecturally interesting" than a "simple" bouncy castle but that doesn't make it **not** a bouncy castle.  I'd probably call it "a really cool bouncy castle", and look forward to ten minutes of peace while my son goes nuts on it.

Answer (score 31):

**Bounce house** is a generic term, at least in the US. [Toys R Us](http://www.toysrus.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=2257594) and [Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/browse/toys/bounce-houses-ball-pits/4171_14521_131360) use the term to broadly categorize these products.

Here are a few usage examples from around the US:

- New York Post: [Bounce house goes airborne with kids inside](http://nypost.com/2015/05/25/bounce-house-goes-airborne-with-kids-inside/)
- NBC Miami: [Children Hurt as Waterspout Uproots Bounce House](http://www.nbcmiami.com/news/local/Children-Hurt-as-Waterspout-Uproots-Bounce-House-Police-304916201.html)
- Denver Post: [2 kids injured as Colorado bounce house blows away](http://www.denverpost.com/breakingnews/ci_25881897/2-kids-injured-colorado-bounce-house-blows-away)

Variations like *bouncy house* and *inflatable bounce house* are also used, but less commonly than *bounce house*.

Comment: Strange that the term "Bounce House" is always associated with injuries...

Comment: @DanielGriscom At least in the news it is.  But the term is also used when the media isn't around!

Comment: In Boston, we are apparently wishy-washy between "[bounce house](http://www.boston.com/news/nation/2014/06/02/two-kids-hurt-yet-another-bounce-house-accident/IBVKsPzoZQZg6v6J0t8mbP/story.html)" and "[bouncy house](http://www.boston.com/news/local/new-hampshire/2014/10/12/toddlers-seriously-injured-when-bouncy-house-thrown-wind/1PUgI65k299DZ4c2nhibAJ/story.html)" — although personally, I've only heard "bouncy house".

Comment: Would you expect a bounce house that is behaving normally to make the news?

Answer (score 7):

Every child I grew up with would refer to them as a **moon bounce**.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflatable_castle);

> They have been marketed with such names as "Bounce House",
>   "Bouncies","Moon Bounce", "Boingalow", "Astrojump", "Moonwalk", "Jolly
>   Jump" and "Spacewalk". "Brinca brinca" [is] another name commonly used by
>   Latinos

Comment: Out of curiosity, when and where did you grow up?

Comment: @Kevin in the Northeastern United States, in the 80's/90's

Comment: I've never heard it as anything else as well, grew up in the Northwestern US in the 90's, and live in the Northeastern US now.

Answer (score 7):

Worked for about five years at accompany that rented these out in the USA, and they were called jumping castles (when they resembled castles, and were for jumping in) and inflatables the rest of the time. This includes slides, Velcro walls, or obstacle courses as your picture indicates. The company has them listed generally as 'inflatables' on their site.

[All About Parties](http://www.allaboutpartiesaz.com/)

Note that jumping castles or bouncy houses are simply a more specific for of inflatable. The following photos are all from their website.

[image: Jumping Castle]

*Jumping Castle, Bouncy House, or simply Bounce*

[image: 45 foot obstacle course]

*45 foot obstacle course Inflatable*

[image: 27 foot dual-lane Inflatable slide]

*27 foot dual-lane Inflatable slide*

I would add that there may also be regional differences. My experience was all in the southwestern USA.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia they're known as 'Jumping Castles'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.This post would be improved by providing additional support for the use of this term: perhaps a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.